# How to make Javascript/jQuery key events work with Screen Readers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accessibility, keyboard-navigation

I have the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/37x0f7eh/) containing a navigation bar consisting of a few categories with sub categories in them.

```
<div class="navigation-bar">
    <div class="category-container" tabindex="0" role="navigation" aria-labelledby="category-1">
        <h4 id="category-1">Category</h4>
        <ul class="subcategory">
            <li tabindex="1"><a href="#">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li tabindex="2"><a href="#">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li tabindex="3"><a href="#">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li tabindex="4"><a href="#">Subcategory</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="category-container" tabindex="0" role="navigation" aria-labelledby="category-2">
        <h4 id="category-2">Category</h4>
        <ul class="subcategory">
            <li tabindex="1"><a href="#">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li tabindex="2"><a href="#">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li tabindex="3"><a href="#">Subcategory</a></li>
            <li tabindex="4"><a href="#">Subcategory</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am leveraging Javascript/jQuery like so:

```
$(function(){
    $(".category-container").keydown(function(e){
        // down arrow shows the category sub menu, if said sub menu is hidden
        if($(this).find(".subcategory").is(":hidden") && e.keyCode === 40){
            $(this).find(".subcategory").toggle();
        }
        // esc hides the category sub menu, if said sub menu is visible
        else if($(this).find(".subcategory").is(":visible") && e.keyCode === 27){
            $(this).find(".subcategory").toggle();
        }
    });

    $("a").keydown(function(e){
        // if we press tab on the last sub category, hide current category sub menu
        if($(this).closest(".subcategory").find("li:last-child a").is(":focus") && e.keyCode === 9){
            $(this).closest(".subcategory").toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see, the navigation works very well for people without disabilities, meaning you can use your mouse to explore the navigation bar using simple CSS event handlers.

For keyboard accessibility, I have these very specific instructions:

- Navigate from category to category via `tab` press.
- To open a sub categories menu, press the `down arrow` key.
- To close a sub categories menu, press the `esc` key.
- To navigate from sub menu item to sub menu item, press `tab`.

All of that functionality is already in place thanks to Javascript/jQuery. **My challenge** comes when using a screen reader, like JAWS or NVDA, which is currently preventing my Javascript/JQuery from working as above described for keyboard navigation purposes.

To be specific, I cannot access the `subcategories` via any combination of `keypress` events I could come up with.

**Question:** Is it possible to *fix* this code to be keyboard accessible and ARIA compliant? Even if it is not possible, an explanation towards why it would not be possible to fix this code is better than nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code lacks of some `aria` attributes to indicate that your menu is a dropdown menu and explanations to describe which shortcut you might use. `Down arrow` and `esc` key are not commonly used in web navigation.

Something like `aria-haspopup` for instance.

You can see some examples with a simple google search "aria dropdown menu", like:

- http://codepen.io/grayghostvisuals/pen/ltjDa
- http://staff.washington.edu/tft/tests/menus/html5/

I would say that the most difficult part is to have some shortcuts which will work intuitively.

The first example is something I like because it can be used with the `tab` key and add a pragmatic left/right (but optional) arrow shortcut to go to the next category.

Concerning your code, I think that the down arrow might override the navigation key of your screenreader, so using `enter` key will be something which should work in your case.

Comment: First of all thanks for looking into it, I can't work on this answer myself until Monday so stand by for my reply. The biggest issue I have is the specific navigation instructions with down arrow, esc and tab, but if I have proof that this navigation cannot happen then I can argue with my superior in order to better adhere to whatever is best practice.

Comment: I agree with Adam, the down arrow will interfere with screen readers.

Comment: @MathieuG I agree with both of you, I have been doing lots and lots of prototypes on jsfiddle and I find that Adam's suggestions are the best approach. All I need to do is keep in mind the ARIA changes with jquery even handlers like `focus`, `blur`, and `keydown`, using plenty of `is` to check the status of the dropdown elements and updating them accordingly... and keeping it real simple is best. It is much like adding a third dimension to the code, exclusively for the screen reader, but it works very well.